# Custom Unit in adobe illustrator

Tags: scripting, adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to add a custom unit to adobe illustrator? I searched the web but there seems to be no option, not even via scripting. Also: maybe it is possible in any other program similar to illustrator, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can just change units while adding new document and units can be from the following list

```
Centimeters 
Qs
Inches 
Pixels
Millimeters
Picas
Points
```

For reference, you can check units property on Pg. No. 44 && 45 from the following link

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2015_3/Illustrator%20JavaScript%20Scripting%20Reference.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Charu you cannot change the default units (cm, qs, in, px, mm, pt or picas) - however, due to the nature of your question, not specifying which unit you're interested in, you can always manually convert your custom unit in the above ones by using an online unit converter, such as this one. https://www.digitaldutch.com/unitconverter/length.htm
it has every possible Length unit you need:
[See uploaded screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBVcI.png)